# Use Unix-based commands with Anaconda in Windows Operating System

Tags: python, anaconda

I used to use several Unix-based commands with Anaconda 2 (i.e., Python 2.7) in Windows 7. For example, these commands `ls, mkdir, rm,...` can work properly with Anaconda Command Prompt.

Recently, I have upgraded to Windows 10 and installed Anaconda 3 running with Python 3.5. These command mentioned above cannot be used in the Anaconda 3. I have tried to uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda 3 for times, but it can work as before.

Any one has a suggestion?

Comment: you might be using `ipython` instead of the `python` repl. Try typing `ipython` in the terminal.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

At the command line in Anaconda Prompt, use conda to install the m2-base utilities:

```
conda install m2-base
```

This will give you the basic linux commands.

Comment: On Windows, I was hating my work pace because I am used to linux and bash commands. Everytime ls, cat and other cool stuff would just give me some error. your `conda install m2-base` was a great solution. Took 2 minutes, and now I can run bash commands in my miniconda3 prompt on windows.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to have access to those commands on your windows machine would be to use [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html).  You can [install](http://cygwin.com/install.html) that.  Then open a "Cygwin Bash Shell" and in this shell you will be able to use `ls, mkdir, rm, ...` as well as create conda environments etc.  You can use this instead of your command prompt if you want.