# I need help regarding jupyter Notebbok

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

i am not able to use some of the features of jupyter notebook like `!cat` because these doesn't work on windows and due to that it is becoming difficult to do some assignments so if there is an alternative other than using linux or mac?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What problem are you running into? If you do not provide any information people won't be able to help  you. Please provider any program output or error message you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Anaconda distribution of python with jupyter on Windows. Once that is installed you can use bash commands from this question:

[Use Unix-based commands with Anaconda in Windows Operating System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345136/use-unix-based-commands-with-anaconda-in-windows-operating-system)